# Python Flask filter results in template depending on selected checkbox in form (wtf)

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a database with a few rooms at the moment, a user can search on the indexpage for a room in a city by typing in a cityname. He will be redirected to the resultpage where he finds all rooms in this city.

In my database each rooms has a few boolean properties, f.e. "`has_wlan`" or "`has_tv`"

On this resultpage there should be a filter function, where you see all these properties and f.e. if you want to see all rooms which have tv, you check the checkbox `has_tv` and the results shall be reloaded where only rooms are shown with boolean value `True` for `has_tv`.

For this I crreated a new form (WTF-Forms) and I included it in my method which loads all results:

```
@app.route('/<findroomcity>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def find_room(findroomcity):

form = FilterZimmerForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(Zimmer.haustiere_erlaubt.is_(False)).all()
else:
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.order_by(desc("stadt")).all()  


try:
    location = geolocator.geocode(findroomcity)
    #location2 = geolocator.geocode("Dortmund" + " Am Hombruchsfeld")
    mymap = Map(
    identifier="view-side",
    lat=location.latitude,
    lng=location.longitude,
    markers=[(location.latitude, location.longitude)],
    zoom = 12
    )
    sleep(1)
    markerlist = []
    for room in all_rooms_in_city:
        if room.stadt == findroomcity.lower():
            try:
                location2 = geolocator.geocode(room.stadt + " " + room.strasse + " " + room.hausnr)
                markerlist.append((location2.latitude, location2.longitude))
            except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
                print "in der schleife timeout", e  
            except AttributeError as e:
                print "in der schleife attributeerror", e   

    mymap.markers['//maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'] = markerlist


except AttributeError as e:
    flash("Ort nicht gefunden")
    print e
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
    print e

sleep(1)
return render_template('zimmer_gefunden.html', mymap=mymap, all_rooms_in_city=all_rooms_in_city, findroomcity=findroomcity, form=form)
```

The result page also loads a google map with markers, but this works well. The question is how do I reload the results where only rooms are shown with checked items from the checkboxlist?

[image]

So this is the relevant piece of code:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(Zimmer.haustiere_erlaubt.is_(False)).all()
else:
    all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.order_by(desc("stadt")).all()
```

At this moment I just try to filter for all rooms where "haustiere_erlaubt" is false this is just for testing but not even this works. The plan is to replace the False with `form.haustiere_erlaubt.data`for all other boolean values aswell.

Comment: Could you try `filter(Zimmer.haustiere_erlaubt == False)` or `filter_by(haustiere_erlaubt=False)` instead? But I actually suspect that your form does not validate. Check that before.

Comment: I tried, doesnt make any difference

Comment: Then the form did not validate. Make sure that it does or show the errors to the user.

Comment: okay it works now, there was a problem with one of my fields, I dont know which but I'll figure it out